# WCF: File Transfer without using HTTP

Tags: wcf, file, transfer

Good day all.

I am completely new to WCF and Im learning as I am going.

I just would like to know, what are the best way of downloading or  uploading files by getting it directly from disc and not via http.

Currently I am using WCF and http using the chunk way, but for a specific set of file I need to do it differently.Any tips, help or links will help me alot

Answer (score 0):

When you transfer large files  the best way to using “WCF service + HTTP”, we can use the following types of bindings:

wsHttpBinding
basicHttpBinding

Answer (score 0):

Where do your clients reside? If the transfer is within the same network, you can take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37057/File-Transfer-using-WCF-and-Socket) article. Otherwise, check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) information on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Client wont be on same network amd it will be small files in general